# At what point should you collapse many parameters into (e.g.) struct to improve readability in function headers?

Tags: coding-style, readability

While making a struct creates some overhead at run-time, packaging a bunch of frequently-used-together variables can dramatically increase code readability.  How do you balance the two?  I was just asked to "unroll" a struct that contained 12 variables, which now makes calls to the function header monolithic; it seems poor style and I wanted to know what others thought.

Comment: [«11. If you have a procedure with ten parameters, you probably missed some.»](http://www.cs.yale.edu/homes/perlis-alan/quotes.html)

Comment: what programming language are you asking about?

Comment: Is this new code or maintaining legacy code?

Comment: I was asking about general good practices, but the code that sparked the question is C++ (adding new features to a 10-year-old codebase).

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if it turned out after benchmarking that not using a struct did not make the code any faster. Although many people believe it, just because code is less readable and “more low-level” doesn't mean it will be any faster. In fact, the opposite can be true.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How many functions do you have that uses those parameters?

If you have 4 functions that all take the same 12 parameters, it's a sign that you probably should bundle those into a cohesive set.

If you have 4 functions that use say... 8 of the parameters, then maybe those 8 should be bundled up.

**But this is rather missing a little bit of the point.** Bundling into a struct is not your only option. You can also break up the function so that instead of one big function needing 12 parameters, you have 8 more focused ones that need one or two parameters. Smaller functions are easier to test, easier to reuse, easier to write, easier to maintain.

Answer (score 2):

Keep in mind that typically the solution is not always collapsing some of the arguments into a distinct data structure. Most of the times you should split the functions into multiple ones because probably it's the function itself that does multiple things.

I remember Uncle Bob in *Clean Code* saying there should be at most 2 and only in special cases 3 arguments to a function. This might be very difficult to achieve all the time (take for example functions with timeouts where the timeout and timeunit take 2 arguments).

On the other hand *Code Complete* is not so rigorous, saying there shouldn't be more than 7 but emphasizing on the fact that in higher-level languages this can be avoided.